# Condensing Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reorganize

I just have a simple question, I really appreciate everyones input, you have been a great help to my project. I have an additional question about data frames in R.

I have data frame that looks similar to something like this:

```
    C <- c("","","","","","","","A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D")
    D <- c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,1,1,4,2,2,5,2,1,4,2)
    G <- list(C=C,D=D)
    T <- as.data.frame(G)
    T
   C  D
1     NA
2     NA
3     NA
4     2
5     NA
6     NA
7     1
8  A  1
9  B  4
10 D  2
11 A  2
12 B  5
13 D  2 
14 A  1
15 B  4
16 D  2
```

I would like to be able to condense all the repeat characters into one, and look similar to this:

```
    J B C E
  1   2 1
  2 A 1 2 1
  3 B 4 5 4
  4 D 2 2 2
```

So of course, the data is all the same, it is just that it is condensed and new columns are formed to hold the data. I am sure there is an easy way to do it, but from the books I have looked through, I haven't seen anything for this!

**EDIT I edited the example because it wasn't working with the answers so far. I wonder if the NA's, blanks, and unevenness from the blanks are contributing??**

Comment: @ Joyce: Avoid using "T" as a variable name, since by default R has it set to TRUE and S won't let you overwrite it at all.

Comment: `C` is also a function name as is `df`. For the most part avoiding all of these is a courtesy to your own brain.

Comment: You can construct a data.frame in one step: `my.df <- data.frame(C = c("","","","","","","","A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D"), D = c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,1,1,4,2,2,5,2,1,4,2))`.

Answer (score 1):

here´s a reshape solution:

```
require(reshape)
cast(T, C ~ ., function(x) x)
```

Comment: Turns out this works well on my example data, but when I try to do this with my real data it doesn't work so well. I have blanks and NA values, I wonder if that is screwing it up? This is the error message: Using SigIntensity as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Error in x[[v]][thisvar] <- if (N > 1L) value[n + seq_len(nv)] else value : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In if (lengths == 1) return(data) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Yes, looks like the problem is the NA's as I tried your solution with the new test example. Also, because not all of the data has exactly three data points, it is causing a lot of problems. Is there a way to use this program while not having to reorganize my data frames?

Answer (score 1):

Changed T to df to avoid a bad habit.  Returns a list, which my not be what you want but you can convert from there.

```
C <- c("A","B","D","A","B","D","A","B","D")
D <- c(1,4,2,2,5,2,1,4,2)
my.df <- data.frame(id=C,val=D)

ret <- function(x) x
by.df <- by(my.df$val,INDICES=my.df$id,ret)
```

Comment: For the example data it worked okay. I would like to be able to coerce it into a data frame which is what the example that EDi showed. When I try to do this on my real data, this is what I get. Error in names(IND) <- deparse(substitute(INDICES))[1L] : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: `df` is a function name and you are overwriting an existing version of `identical`.

Comment: @Joyce Both Dwin and my solution failed on your real data apparently...which illustrates the importance of good test data!  The data you posted had no NAs and was balanced (e.g. each letter had an equal number of observations).  Post some test data that better reflects your problem :-)

Comment: I reedited my post to illustrate the test example that more clearly demonstrates my real data. Thank you for your help thus far!

Answer (score 1):

This *seems* to get the results you are looking for. I'm assuming it's OK to remove the `NA` values since that matches the desired output you show.

```
T <- na.omit(T)
T$ind <- ave(1:nrow(T), T$C, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(T, direction = "wide", idvar = "C", timevar = "ind")
#    C D.1 D.2 D.3
# 4      2   1  NA
# 8  A   1   2   1
# 9  B   4   5   4
# 10 D   2   2   2

library(reshape2)
dcast(T, C ~ ind, value.var = "D", fill = "")
#   C 1 2 3
# 1   2 1  
# 2 A 1 2 1
# 3 B 4 5 4
# 4 D 2 2 2
```